# mysql - how to count how many records there are in a table and then only get 20?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forum

I'm building a forum for a school project and I want to display only say 20 posts per page, for a forum. However, I still need to know how much total posts there are, to display the page listing.
I could run a mysql query that limits the number of posts to 20, and then, run another query that would count how many records there are in a table, but that would be 2 queries. Isn't there a way to both get a limited number of records AND in the same query, to get the number of records total?

Thanks.

Comment: Two queries are probably the best way to go.  I think you are missing a key point of SQL queries . . . the columns are the same for each row being returned.  You can't have result set where one row is a "count" and then other rows have multiple columns of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subquery

```
select *,
       (select count(*) from your_table) as total_count
from your_table
order by some_column
limit 20
```

Comment: This does mean that for every record there will be an extra field `total_count` tho.. So two queries will be more effecient

Comment: No, 2 queries will not be more efficient. The subquery will not be calculated for every row. Only once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding juergen's post:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) AS total FROM tablePRDER BY id LIMIT 0, 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $total = $row['total'];     /* Total rows of the whole table */
    $id = $row['id'];           /* Id of limitted query (20) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from your_table
inner join (select count(*) as total_count from your_table) tc
order by some_column
limit 20;
```